# Having conflict with my jquery pop-up and auto resize textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Having problem while using jQuery, I think there having a conflict between this two script. I don't know where.

While I'm trying to put this (pop up window script).

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('a.popup-window').click(function()  {
        
        var popupBox = $(this).attr('href');
        $(popupBox).fadeIn(400);
        
        var popMargTop = ($(popupBox).height() + 24) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($(popupBox).width() + 24) / 2;
        
        $(popupBox).css({
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });
        
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(400);
        return false;
    });
    
    $('button.close, #mask').live('click', function () {
        
            $('#mask, .popupInfo').fadeOut(400, function () {
                    $('mask').remove();
            });
            return false;
    });

});
$(document).keyup(function(e)  {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $('#mask, .popupInfo, #popup-box').fadeOut(400);
        return false;
    }
})
</script>
```

My auto resize textarea will not work, the script of auto resize text area are. But the pop up window will work. And if I put away the script in pop up window, the auto resize textarea will work.

```html
<script src='http://usvac.bugs3.com/js/jquery.autosize.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://usvac.bugs3.com/js/jquery.autosize.js'></script>
<script>
            $(function(){
                $('.normal').autosize();
                $('.animated').autosize({append: "\n"});
            });
</script>
```

Comment: <script src='http://usvac.bugs3.com/js/jquery.autosize.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://usvac.bugs3.com/js/jquery.autosize.js'></script> try to remove one of this two scripts.

Comment: yes, one will work and the other will not.. i want both works in one page.

Comment: remove jquery.autosize.min.js because jquery.autosize.js will do the same thing. think like this: the same function let`s say "autosize()" it`s declared 2 times. think before you want something.

Comment: if i remove one of them my autoresize will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap up your auto resize textarea JQuery code with an anonymous function:

```
(function($) {
  $('.normal').autosize();
  $('.animated').autosize({append: "\n"});
})(jQuery);
```

Your popup code:

```
(function($) {
$('a.popup-window').click(function()  {

    ........
    ........
});

$('button.close, #mask').live('click', function () {

       .......
       .......
});


if (e.keyCode == 27) {
   .......
   .......
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: and in your jquery popup you have ready function twice..wrap it up using single ready function and instead of `ready` function, pass the `$` symbol as parameter like i did for auto resize..

Comment: i didn't get it, sorry im new in jquery, btw when i remove the conflict this code not works also. :|